# Split an array into two identical arrays by key value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
MyArray (
    [0] => Array (
                            [board_id] => 1047999
                            [added_date] => 2013-02-28 11:14:02
                            [type] => 4
                           )
    [1] => Array (
                           [board_id] => 1047999
                           [added_date] => 2013-02-28 11:14:02
                           [type] => 1
                          )
    [2] => Array (
                          [board_id] => 1047999
                          [added_date] => 2013-02-28 11:14:02
                          [type] => 4
                          )
    [3] => Array (
                          [board_id] => 1047999
                          [added_date] => 2013-02-28 11:14:02
                          [type] => 1
                          )
)
```

How can I split this array by `type` and keep the exact same array structure? I.e. I would have MyArrayT4 with two subarrays, and MyArrayT1 with two subarrays?

TIA!

Comment: the last entry, is there `[3] => Array(`missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use array_filter like this
EDIT use array_values to reset

```
$filtering = function($type) use($your_array) {
    $filtered = array_filter($your_array, function($r) use($type) {
        return $r['type'] == $type;
    });

    return array_values($filtered);
};


$array_1 = $filtering->__invoke('4');
$array_2 = $filtering->__invoke('1');
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pass the input array as a parameter instead of `use`? Also the `__invoke` is unnecessary `$filtering()` is enough.

Comment: I had no idea you could do javascript-style `var = function() {}` instructions in PHP. That's awesome.

Comment: @AustinMullins `Closures` are supported since PHP 5.3 ... yea... you can pass the array..

Comment: Thanks silly. You may want to add in your answer that one should use array_values to reset the array numbering, otherwise loops can get messed up!

Comment: Wanted to post a response, saw this and hit pause. Great one.